# Multiplying doubles. Answer keeps rounding

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to multiple a double price variable with a int item quantity variable.

Currently I am having an issue with the correct format to display the result of the calculation. for example:

I have two items in my database, one has a price value of 2.99, the other 4.00. Each item quantity is 1. this brings the total to 6.99. I want this displayed but instead my integer value is rounding to 7.

Here is the code:

```
 object foundQty = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["coffeeQty"];
 int Qty = Convert.ToInt32(foundQty);


 double price = setPriceList(IDOfCart);

 combinedPrice = price * Qty;

 holdingPrice += Convert.ToInt32(combinedPrice);
```

Can anyone tell me why this a double value is not being displayed?

Comment: Where is the declaration of combinedPrice? what is holdingPrice?

Comment: Use *decimal* if you want to manipulate decimal quantities like money. Only use *double* for physical quantities like length or mass. Doubles can only represent fractions that have a denominator that is a power of two, which means that they have to round off quantities like 99 / 100. Decimals represent fractions that have powers of ten in the denominator.

Comment: An integer is a whole number, and will round to the nearest whole number: `holdingPrice += Convert.ToInt32(combinedPrice);`  Keep the values as double instead of converting to int, and use string.Format to format the value as two decimal places.

Comment: Im not sure what your getting at. You are converting a double to an Int32. Of course its going to round.

Comment: Please show all the code we need to reproduce your problem

Comment: I think it would be `string.Format("Here is price to two decimal places: {0:#.##}", price * Qty);`

Comment: @AaronLS Thanks for your description of the string.format. I can see what you're doing here but what im not sure is how i add to the holdingPrice variable thats holds the total amount of money.... then convert it to 2d.p I.e the code I have posted is in a for loop and adds the results of all of the prices multiples by the qtys to give a total

Comment: Again, as we have said, you are rounding to a whole number by concerting to Int32, holdingPrice and combinedPrice must be `double` or `decimal`, not `int`, and you need to remove `Convert.ToInt32`.  The code you show doesn't show where your variables are declared, so we can only guess what type you declared them as, which is very important in this case.

Comment: "For example, 21, 4, and −2048 are integers; 9.75 ... are not integers." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer

Comment: Ok got this sorted. I did as said and made sure all of my vars were of one type, in my case doubles, then added them to a list array and used the .sum() method and it now works perfectly thanks for all your help.

Comment: @user1352057: Look into using decimal for money types. It will save you much trouble in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integers by definition are always whole numbers.

If you want to display a double value then display a double value, don't convert to and then display an integer ;-)